# Sed dynamic substitute, the unix way?

Tags: shell, sed

Got a bunch of files with domain qualified names in them, looking to replace them by their ip.

Can I do that with one line of shell ( bash ) ?

Typical input file ( nagiosconf ) :

```
define host {
        host_name                       host1
        use                             model
        alias                           myalias
        address                         myhost.domain

}
define service {
        host_name                       hostname
        use                             Modele_Ping
}
```

The idea is to replace "myhost.domain" by its ip ( as returned by nslookup or other tools ).

I can always script it, but I was wondering if there was a unix smart way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE! [Take a tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with our philosophy, and edit your question to provide more information, as well as better formatting. It's not clear what you're asking - please provide examples of input and desired output, and rules that sed should obey.

Comment: Are you looking something like this ? sed -r "s/\w+\.\w+/xx.xx.xx.xx/" file

Comment: nope ip should be obtained from a system utility like nslookup or ping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may need some tweaking, but:

```
<source_file while read -r line; do
    part=$(echo "$line" | egrep -o '\w+\.\w+')
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        addr=$(dig $part +short | head -n1)
        echo "${line/$part/$addr}"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

This will look up any domains of the form "part1.part2". Mess with the regex to change what exactly it tries to look up. It will only look up one address per line.